# How to reduce parameters needed in recursive function definition (for calculation of a*b)

Tags: python, recursion, parameters, arguments

I have a recursive function that calculates `a*b` however when I call it I don't want to have to give it a value: `recursive_sum(5,5,0)` where `0` is the saved sum.

```
def recursive_sum(a,b,saved):
    if b == 1:
        saved+=a
        return saved
    saved += a
    b -= 1
    b*recursive_sum(a,b,saved)
```

*I understand this is a very simple example*

When I add the line `save=0` so I don't have to pass the pointless argument, obviously, the value is reset to `0` with each iteration.

**My Question:** is there a way to implement my function to work with the call `recursive_sum(2,2)` and not have to worry about passing `0` to `saved`?

Comment: you can use something like `def recursive_sum(a,b,saved=0):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has two issues.

First, you've not included a default value for `saved` in the declaration of your function (though you mention trying to). I suspect when you tried it, you actually did something different (passing a keyword argument in the recursive call).

Second, you're not `return`ing the result of the recursive call (you're instead multiplying the result by `b`, which doesn't make any sense and doesn't do anything useful, since you discard the result).

Here's a fixed version:

```
def recursive_sum(a,b,saved=0): # provide default value for saved here
    saved+=a # minor improvement: moved this line here rather than repeating it twice below
    if b == 1:
        return saved
    b -= 1
    return recursive_sum(a,b,saved) # return result of recursive call (and don't multiply)
```

I suspect when you tried using a default value before, you also (or instead) put `saved=0` in the recursive call at the end of the function (not only on the `def` line). That won't work correctly, as it passes `0` as a keyword argument, ignoring the value of `saved` you already have.

This version of the code is "tail recursive", since you `return` the result of the recursive call without doing anything else. This kind of recursion has some performance benefits in some other programming languages, but alas, not in Python. Unless you are choosing tail recursion for some specific reason (e.g. you're required use it for a homework assignment), the non-tail recursive code in [RagingRoosevelt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45600707/1405065) is probably better than this version.

Comment: what does it mean to `return` the function? why is that different to calling it?

Comment: @Arkan `return` is how you specify the value that a function call produces.

Answer (score 2):

This whole approach only really works for integers, but this might set you straight:

```
def recursive_sum(a,b):
    if b == 1:
        return a
    return a + recursive_sum(a, b-1)
```

The idea here is that your return statement needs to call the next iteration of function call and then use the result it receives to calculate it's own return value.  When you write a recursive function, you're really writing f(f(...f(x))).  You have two components to implement:

1. The general (recursive) case - How can you use previous results to calculate the next result in sequence?
2. The base case - How do you determine that you don't need any additional recursion?  In this case, you'll just return a value without calling the function again.

Try implementing a recursive factorial function.  That's perhaps the easiest (except maybe a sum) recursive function to write.

Answer (score 1):

```
def recursive_sum(a,b):
    def iterative_sum(x, saved):
        if x == 0:
            return saved
        else:
            return iterative_sum(x-1, saved+a)
    return iterative_sum(b,0)
```